# Call 2 methods sequentially on the same "button" or reference

Tags: html, button, html-table, jscript

The button/reference should minimize/maximize some text inside a table.

Below you will find 2 functions "blend_in" which maximizes the text in a table and "blend_out" which blends out / minimizes the text in a table.
I implemented this with 2 buttons and would like to have the 2 methods on the same button/reference.

```js
function blend_in(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block'
}

function blend_out(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none'
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      //this button will open the text inside the table.
      <a href="javascript:blend_in('zeile')"> Button 1 </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none;" id="zeile">
    <td>
      (Text of the table) //the text inside the table which will be opened by clicking "Button 1" and closes by clicking "Button 2"
      <a href="javascript:blend_out('zeile')"> Button 2 </a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming the title could be "Toggle a row on click of a link" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple toggle - I use data-attribute to get the target - it can be used for several rows:

```js
window.onload=function() {
  var buts = document.querySelectorAll(".toggleBut");
  for (var i=0;i<buts.length;i++) {
    buts[i].onclick=function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // cancel the click
      var target = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute("data-blend"));
      target.style.display=target.style.display=="none"?"":"none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
a.toggleBut { text-decoration:none }
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="toggleBut" data-blend="zeile1"> Toggle 1 </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none;" id="zeile1">
    <td>Text of the table 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="toggleBut" data-blend="zeile2"> Toggle 2 </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none;" id="zeile2">
    <td>Text of the table 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```